# What happens if a rendez vous point for a single onion service is a relay that uses an old version of Tor?

Tags: onion-services, relays

What happens if a rendez vous point for a single onion service is a relay that uses an old version of Tor that doesn't support the recent single onion service feature?

And if that wouldn't happen if Tor checks for versions before choosing the rendez vous, doesn't it mean that it's easier to do de-anonymization attacks because the possible paths or circuits are much less than if all relays had up to date tor versions?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the client or onion service, the rendezvous point just has two inbound circuits rendezvous at it.

It can't easily determine how many hops were taken to reach it, nor does it matter to it for it's part in the rendezvous protocol.